# Constructing commutative series of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. For every $H\lhd G$ such that $H$ is commutative
>   and $D^{n-1}(G/H)=\{H\}$, there exists a sequence $(G_i)_{i\in[0,n]}$
>   of normal subgroups of $G$ such that: (1) $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is commutative
>   for all $i\in[0,n-1]$, (2) $G_0=G$, and (3) $G_n=\{e\}$.

For $n=1$, the series $G\supset\{e\}$ works.

Let this hold for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Suppose $H$ is a normal commutative subgroup of $G$ such that $D^n(G/H)=\{H\}$. Moreover, $D^n(G)\subset H$.

I am not able to see what I have to do here to be able to use the induction hypothesis. What should be the strategy?

Comment: What does the notation $D^{n-1}(G/H)$ mean? I’m *guessing* $[0,n-1]$ are the *integers* $i$ with $0\leq i\leq n-1$ (somewhat uncommon but not obscure notation), but don’t know about $D^{n-1}(G/H)$.